# Should I use one single CancellationToken for multiple methods?

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

Here is some of my code:

```
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    
    response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, tokenSource.Token);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using (var readStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        var length = 0;
        while ((length = await readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, tokenSource.Token)) != 0)
        {
            //...
            if (waitTime)
                await Task.Delay(waitTime, tokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
```

Can I use the CancellationToken like that? Or is that the correct way to write it?

Comment: Is the cancellation token relevant for all of the methods? If yes, then sure. If not, then no.

Comment: Yes but CancellationTokenSource implements IDisposable. Make it `using var toenSource` if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's normal to create a token source once and then have a tree of methods take the token and use it for cancellation.